# Why changing information in MongoDB doesn't change it on the site with out reloading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

thanks in advance for your help.

When I change the user's avatar in the modal window, it does not change on the page without reloading the page.  I do not quite understand what to do in this case, although there are guesses that I need to do something with useEffect, but I do not understand what exactly.

I'm relatively new to React, don't judge too harshly.)

```
const ProfileUserInfo = () => {
    const { store } = useContext(Context)

    const params = useParams()
    const userId: string | undefined = params.user_id // UserId from link

    const SERVER_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL 

    const [user, setUser] = useState<UserInfoResponse>() // User data is stored here


    // Fetching user data from MongoDB to visualise it on page
    useEffect(() => {
        store.getUserInfo(userId)
            .then((response) => setUser(response?.data))
    }, [])


    const [isAvatarModal, setAvatarModal] = useState<boolean>(false) // Modal



    return (
        <div className="profile-page__user">

            <div className='profile-page__user__avatar' onClick={() => setAvatarModal(!isAvatarModal)}>
                <img src={`${SERVER_URL}/avatar/${user?.avatar}`} className="non-draggable" alt='avatar'/>
            </div>


            <AvatarModal isAvatarModal={isAvatarModal} setAvatarModal={setAvatarModal} />


            <div className='profile-page__user__info unselectable'>

                <div className='profile-page__user__info__name'>
                    <p>Имя: <span>{user?.name}</span></p>
                </div>

                <div className='profile-page__user__info__email'>
                    <div className='profile-page__user__info__email__text'>
                        <p>E-mail: <span>{user?.email}</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div className='profile-page__user__info__email__is-confirmed'>
                        <img src={user?.isActivated ? GreenCircle : RedCircle} alt='circle' />
                        <p>{user?.isActivated ? 'Подтверждён' : 'Не подтверждён'}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    )
}

export default ProfileUserInfo
```

I tried reloading the page when changing the avatar (`window.location.reload()`) and it works, but I want the data to change without reloading if it's possible.

Also, i tryed to put in useEffect dependencies `useEffect(() => {code}, [store.user, userId])`(i do not why i tryed to do it, but still...)

Answer (score 0):

in this case, your useEffect executes only one time. The subsequent values of user variable are not updated. You need to add a variable in the dependancy array of useEffect. Whenever that variable changes, useEffect will execute. But in this case It can't be user because that will create an infinite loop.

```js
   // Fetching user data from MongoDB to visualise it on page
    useEffect(() => {
        store.getUserInfo(userId)
            .then((response) => setUser(response?.data))
    }, [X]) // <-- whenever X changes, useEffect will execute
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I don't know what to put there.  Perhaps I should create `const [updateInfo, setUpdateInfo] = useState<boolean>(false)` and change the state value when I need to update the information. For example, `axios.post(url, formData).then(() => setUpdateInfo(!updateInfo))`. Is this a good decision?

Comment: Yes you can get a different variable that trigger useEffect or use useReducer.

Other solutions you could pass your API call to react-query. so Whenever, you want to refresh your page with the data from the backend, you can call 
```
queryClient.invalidateQueries('QueryKey');

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! 
The problem was solved by creating a variable and adding it to the useEffect dependency array.
Unfortunately, I did not know about react-query, so I will study the information and possibly change the code.
Thanks again)